# Jquery - Onclick insert div into subdivs

Tags: php, jquery, html

The following function appends on-click a div containing an image, to each main div from the "edit" class.

I need to **insert** on-click a div into each subdiv from c.$k class. All the sub-divs from c1/c2 class have unique ids.

Basically I need to display a rrdtool created graph inside each sub-div which represents a device with unique IP. (the id of the sub-div)

In other words I need to get the id from each class c.$k div and use it as 'ipx' on var y,

then **insert** a new div class='graph' into each class c.$k div. So we can ignore the second parameter from my function (ipx) as it's not relevant. I need to use the "children" ids from div class='edit'.

This is the first time when I'm using  jquery and any help is more than welcome.

```
function edit_mode(idname,ipx) {
    var x = document.getElementById(idname);
    $(x).toggle( "fade" );
 //   var subdivid = $("#idname").children("div");
    var y = 'http://domain.com/index.php?ip='+ipx;
    $("#"+idname+" img:last-child").remove();
    $("<div class='graph'><img src='"+y+"'></div>").appendTo(x);
};
```

The PHP code:

```
 $k=1;
    $t="";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          if ($row['id'] != $t) {
                if ($t != "") {echo "</div>";}
                echo "<div onclick=\"edit_mode('".$row['idDevice']."','".$row['IP']."')\">".$row['name']."  ".$row['IP'] ."</div><br><div class=\"edit\"  id=\"".$row['idDevice']."\">";
      $t = $row['id'];
      $k = 1;
          }
    echo "<div id=\"".$row['IP']."\" class=\"c".$k."\"><form method=\"post\" action=\"edit.php?idDevice=".$idDevice."\">";
    .................................................................
    echo "</form></div>";
    $k = 1+($k % 2);
    }
```

I've done this:

```
function edit_mode(idname) {
    var x = document.getElementById(idname);
    $(x).toggle( "fade" );
    var subdivid = $.map($('#idname > div'), function(child) { return child.id; }); 
    var y = 'http://domain.com/index.php?ip='+subdivid;
    $("#"+idname+" img:last-child").remove(); 
    var el = document.createElement('div');
            el.className="graph";
            el.innerHTML = '<img src='+y+'>' ;
            document.getElementById(subdivid).appendChild(el);
```

This is doing exactly what I want, except that is working for one parent div with one child. The question would be now: how can I modify this function to work when I have dynamically created arrays of divs (idname) with children (subdivid).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the second parameter to `edit_mode` is the `id` of the sub div with class `c.$k`, so you can use it for appending the div with image

```
function edit_mode(idname,ipx) {
    var x = document.getElementById(idname);
    $(x).toggle( "fade" );
 //   var subdivid = $("#idname").children("div");
    var y = 'http://domain.com/index.php?ip='+ipx;
    $("#"+idname+" img:last-child").remove();
    $("<div class='graph'><img src='"+y+"'></div>").appendTo('#' + ipx);
};
```